# How to make {{shortcodes}} in node, express, jade app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates, express, pug

When I use something like #{user.name} in my input it spits out a string with "#{user.name}". What I would like to do is get data from my database by adding some {{shortcode}} like the image shows below. It could be any format, doesn't need to be in double curly braces. How can I solve this? Show examples or guide me in the right direction please.

Thank You.

[image]

Comment: You might post your template and the code where you render that template (showing the variables you're passing to it).

Answer (score 1):

you have to return the json object from your client side code called "user" having the property "name" then only you can able to populate the value into the front-end by using `#{user.name}`.